# Does pandas concat give different structure than append?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, append

I read the other posts on SO about this, but still doesn't address my question:

See below image. I appended 4 identical rows and did the same with concat. But the results don't appear visually similar.

[image]

When I tried to extract a column of the data, the results also don't appear visually similar. Are they the same, just for some reason appear different, or am I using it wrong? The desired results are the one from the append, not the concat.

[image]

Question has been answered without needing any codes. But here are my reproducible codes for future viewers:

Given any csv file or the following example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from string import ascii_lowercase as al

# artificial dataframe
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 15
cols = 2
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(rows, cols))
index = pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=rows)

dfdata = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=list(al[:cols]))

# dfdata = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
dfdatanew = pd.DataFrame()

frames = [dfdata.iloc[2],dfdata.iloc[2],dfdata.iloc[2],dfdata.iloc[2]]

dfdatanew = dfdatanew.append(dfdata.iloc[2])
dfdatanew = dfdatanew.append(dfdata.iloc[2])
dfdatanew = dfdatanew.append(dfdata.iloc[2])
dfdatanew = dfdatanew.append(dfdata.iloc[2])

result = pd.concat(frames,axis=0,join='outer')

# compare
print(result)
print(dfdatanew)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. and plz provide text or code not image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide a clear reproducible example in your question with code/data as text.

That said, the error is pretty obvious. You slice **Series** with `iloc` to feed your `concat`. Thus your are concatenating a long Series.

Slice **frames** by using `.iloc[[2]]`:

```
frames = [dfdata.iloc[[2]], dfdata.iloc[[2]], dfdata.iloc[[2]], dfdata.iloc[[2]]]
result = pd.concat(frames)
```

You could also `concat` the Series on `axis=1` and transpose, but this would mess up the dtypes.

*NB. I'm assuming this was a dummy example. If you really want to repeat 4 times a given row, use: `result = dfdata.reindex([2]*4)`.*

Comment: I acknowledge that I did not provide code, but as you have answered, this question didn't need any code... It is just a syntax that I didn't understand, which I felt like I made it clear as what I was asking for. Thank you very much! I will add some codes for future viewers

Comment: @Jesse code is not only important for reproducibility, but also for accessibility. Think of those who need text to speech, an image will be difficult to read ;)

Comment: that's something I hadn't thought of. I will be mindful of images in the future. Thanks